# Several questions about permutations

Tags: permutation

- How many unique permutations are there for all 255 ASCII characters? Ranging from 1 character in length to 255.
- How did you calculate that?
- About how much space (in GB, TB, PB, etc.) would that file take up?
- Roughly how long would it take for a single computer to generate that file?
- Does a project like this exist that possibly uses a bunch of computers on a network or the internet to generate all these permutations?
- Would that project be feasible and could a GPU be used to generate them faster than a CPU?

Comment: At least admit this is a test question you have to answer.  It's also (I feel) rather rude to just paste it in like this and expect answers.

Comment: Doesn't look all that homework-y to me. Especially the latter three questions.

Comment: Would be better with rainbow tables.

Comment: I'm not in school for computers or programming. I have no interest in cracking passwords... nice of you to make that assumption though. I'm just curious about the math involved in figuring this out and curious about how many combinations there would be and how big the file would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 255 + 255^2 + 255^3 + .... +255^255 permutations of 255 characters in  strings ranging from one to 255 chars.

PS: There are only 127 ASCII characters.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, thanks. Sorry, my math is really bad.